# Application pool identity and lsass.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, application-pool

I have a strange problem, when I use application pool as a specific user in my website the Local Security Authority Subsystem Service (lsass.exe) goes high until the IIS hangs.
It's happen in a few minutes for a load of 30 users and above.

I'm using Windows server 2012R2 with IIS 8.5. APPPool Net 4 integrated mode. The pool identity is set to local Windows user. The website has his own application pool and no other website is install on this server. Also, the server is hyper-v virtual machine.

Is this normal behavior?
I have to use this kind of identity to access network folder.

Comment: We'll need more data including (but not limited to): which version of windows (inc. service pack), is it a domain member, how are you using app pool identity, are there many app pools or other local users?

Comment: *In the question* please

Comment: At least you should do some troubleshooting before posting, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2550044/how-to-troubleshoot-high-lsass.exe-cpu-utilization-on-an-active-directory-domain-controllers

Comment: I'm troubleshooting this problem for more than a week.
It's not an active directory, It's a website in a standalone server. when I'm using AppPoolIdentity everything works great, but when I'm using windows user Identity (I must) the IIS become very slow and hangs after few minutes.

Comment: This is puzzling. I googled loads and found this: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23613300/High-CPU-load-with-lsass-exe-process.html (I don't normally refer to experts exchange), where the comment was "Somehow (perhaps with the way our rules were set up), if that page was accessed it would cause a loop, creating a heap of authentications.  This caused lsass.exe to smash the CPU". Is there any way you can offload your remote file operations to a different process like a queuing process or something?

Comment: Here's a more useful link: http://www.guyellisrocks.com/2008/11/lsassexe-and-sql-server-pegging-cpu-at.html. Is this an x64 server? Are you mixing ASP classic and ASP.Net?

Comment: @LexLi this is not an AD server, it's a web server. I only mention this because every google I do points at that link but it's not of any use.

Comment: Hi Nick.McDermaid and thank you for the links.
My server is a x64 win2012R2. I don't use classic ASP and the CPU goes up to 30% max, but it's enough to extremely slow the website and after a while to crush the IIS worker.

It's only happen when I'm using specific user identity, when I'm using applicationPoolIdentity everything works great.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that process does exactly the same things on every machine. Such issues happen more often on an AD machine, but other machines can also. The KB you pointed out is useless as nobody uses Windows Server 2003 any more.

Comment: Hi @Lex, I appreciate your help, but I still can't find the cause. I saw this link before I post the question and I still couldn't figure out how to solve the problem.

Comment: @Tal clearly "The report contains eight broad categories under Diagnostic Results which will contain information and conclusions in the report. These will not always tell the exact cause of the problem but can be used to determine where to investigate in order to find the exact cause." is part of the KB I recommended. If you are not capable of following that, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and don't waste your time.